# app runs fine for the first time after installation but after that keeps on asking to turn on gps even if its on

Tags: java, android, gps, location, android-6.0-marshmallow

*Upon installing the app you will see the app works fine first time showing location as toast message but when you try to use it again, it asks to turn gps on even if its on. INFO: I am developing an app for android version 6. The code for location works fine for below version like android kitkat. Please help me fix this. :(*

**HomeActivity.java**

```
package info.androidhive.fingerprint;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

Context mContext;
GPSTracker gps= new GPSTracker(mContext);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

            mContext = this;
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(HomeActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "You need to grant permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                // Check if GPS enabled
                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    // \n is for new line
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    // Can't get location.
                    gps = new GPSTracker(mContext, HomeActivity.this); // GPS or network is not enabled.
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings.
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            switch (requestCode) {
                case 1: {
                    // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                    if (grantResults.length > 0
                            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        // permission was granted, yay! Do the

                        // contacts-related task you need to do.

                       gps = new GPSTracker(mContext, HomeActivity.this);

                        // Check if GPS enabled
                        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

                            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                            // \n is for new line
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            // Can't get location.
                            // GPS or network is not enabled.
                            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings.
                            gps.showSettingsAlert();
                        }

                    } else {

                        // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                        // functionality that depends on this permission.

                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "You need to grant permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

**GPSTracker.java**

```
package info.androidhive.fingerprint;

/*
Created by sal on 12/4/17.
*/

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
public class GPSTracker extends Service{

private  Context mContext;

// Flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// Flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// Flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // Location
double latitude; // Latitude
double longitude; // Longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1000; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

Activity activity;


public GPSTracker(Context context, Activity activity) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.activity = activity;
    getLocation();
}

public GPSTracker(Context abc) {
    this.mContext=abc;
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {


        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // Getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // No network provider is enabled
            this.canGetLocation=false;
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {


                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, mLocationListener);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // If GPS enabled, get latitude/longitude using GPS Services
        if (isGPSEnabled) {
            if (location == null) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 50);

                } else {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, mLocationListener);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {

                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}


/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app.
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS() {

}


private final LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {

        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
};

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}


/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/Wi-Fi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}


/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog.
 * On pressing the Settings button it will launch Settings Options.
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing the Settings button.
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // On pressing the cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
}
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="info.androidhive.fingerprint">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".FingerprintActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LocationManager class of Google service to check for GPS status:-

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
```

// Demo class for GPS

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v13.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by admin on 18-Apr-17.
 */

public class DemoActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission(); //Step 1
        }

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            Log.e("GPS setting is ", locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) + "");
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();
        } else {
            Log.e("GPS setting is ", locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) + "");
        }
    }

    private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.alertdialog_content))
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Setting", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                        Toast.makeText(DemoActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.alertdialog_cancel_message), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 100);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 100:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), permissions[0] + " Granted...");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Application may not function properly if you deny permission, Please allow Location permission from app settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 100); // you can request again if user deny location request else your logic here
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Screenshots**

1 - Requesting to turn GPS on

[image]

2 - GPS status

[image]

3 - Enable location from setting

[image]

4 - GSP status on

[image]

Comment: where exactly you want me to change the code and do i need to update the dependency ?

Comment: please help ! if you need any more info ask me.

Comment: Put locationmanager line in onCreate() method of your HomeActivity class, and check it using LocationManager class, and set log to check it's response

Comment: After turning GPS on it'll take some time to retrieve your current location

Comment: Try above code and let me know if you don't understand, I made a simple demo for your convenience, So try to understand every steps.

Comment: **I did as you said but now location shows only as 0.0 but does not prompts to open settings**if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
              // grant permission toast
                // Can't get location.
                gps = new GPSTracker(mContext, HomeActivity.this); // GPS or network is not enabled.
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings.
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }
            else {
                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                   // get latitude longitude

Comment: Do not use GPSTracker class to get your current location, refer this link to get current location, this will give you current location updates frequently else you can restrict it also: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdates

Comment: thanks alot the link you provided was really helpful to solve my problem :)

Comment: Glad it helped you and learned a new stuff also.. Happy coding dude.

Answer (score 0):

you are using 
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 50);

which can only turn on Fine Location .
Put A line below this line

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 50);

It will do

Comment: i did but it did not work out. 
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 50);
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 50);

Comment: please help ! if you need any more info ask me.